# How to shift logo to the extreme right using github-flavored-markdown?

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I am writing GitHub [wiki](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/blob/trunk/README.md) for my project. There is something like:

```
[![Join the chat](https://something.svg)](https://some-link)
```

I want to shift this logo to the extreme right.

Initially I was wrapping this in `<p align="right"> </p>` and it's working. But after some update from Github side, it's not working now.

Comment: GitHub does not allow any styling hooks at all and strips them all out. That being the case, I doubt this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bootstrap for Styling your CSS you can use the class pull-right and it will achieve this.

Maybe put your p element in a div and apply the pull right to your div

Comment: No, I am not using anything externally, just using `github-flavored-markdown` for writing documentation for my project.

Comment: My bad I just read to the right.  I see you have a note.  Maybe put it in word and copy paste see if it keeps formatting?